# What is a dashboard web part in SharePoint Online Office 365 intranet?

Tags: sharepoint-online, visual-web-part, dashboard

We are moving our intranet from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint Online Office 365 suite. Can someone please give me a good definition of what a 'Dashboard' web part is in this context?

We cannot seem to agree on how to explain this web part.

Or can anyone guide me where to find good simple definitions of new terminology being used in SharePoint Online?

Is there a good glossary for SharePoint Online?

Thanks. I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

A dashboard is a related group of interactive scorecard and report views that are organized together in a SharePoint or Web-hosted site. For now in SharePoint Online modern experience, there shall be no dashboard web part. You will need to use Excel or PowerBI to create Dashboards and displayed in your sharepoint page.

[Dashboard](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/getting-started-with-dashboards-edc6a32c-85c5-443d-9103-56dcc7bb24a4) in SP 2016 and earlier versions.

Comment: Thanks, Jerry but we have a Dashboard web part in our new intranet! Your definition ''A dashboard is a related group of interactive scorecard and report views that are organized together in a SharePoint or Web-hosted site'' is good - it introduces another term - ''interactive scorecard'' - what are these? pls?

Comment: @Rosario, It may be a custom web part or something else. If possible please upload a screenshot. Basically, interactive scorecard means  chart/graph shows = useful data which you can interactive with it to get what you want. It is not quite different with the dashboards in PowerBI. And of course the functions may vary if it is a custom web part. A bit more information will be useful